# How do I detect when a terminal gets focus in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnome-terminal

I want to be able to time how long I spend in front of a terminal.  I'm thinking the best way will be to have some sort of timer that starts and stops when the terminal gains/loses focus.  And it will have to work with multiple terminals...

Any ideas?  I'm using GNOME.

Comment: Possibly this answer may help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480138/422943

Answer (score 3):

If your terminal shell has easy access to its own X window ID, you're probably doing something wrong! They have nothing to do with each other - e.g. you could (and should) be running long jobs inside `screen` which could in theory be outputting to any number of terminals anywhere in the world.

That being said, the way I solve this problem is by using the prompt's ability to update a terminal's "status"/"title" to report the shell's PID, as with the following prompt:

```
PS1=\u@\H:\w\$\ \[\e]2;\u@\H:\w [$$]\a\]
```

Any pseudo-terminal showing the shell with this prompt and PID 6399 have a title like `user@host:~ [6399]`. *Then*, using a tool like [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/), you can write a bash script such as this:

```
win_from_pid() {
   type wmctrl &>/dev/null || return 1
   wmctrl -l | awk '/^.*\['"$1"'\]$/ { print $1 }'
}
```

This searches the window list and gives you the X Window ID(s) of any ending with that title. Thus, the function `win_from_pid $$` can tell you your window ID(s) on the same host running the script, if any. You can figure out how to determine focus from there. :)

Answer (score 2):

I expect you'll have to listen in on the X-window messages for the appropriate FOCUS message. Not sure how easy/difficult that will be though.

Alternatively https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014822/how-to-know-which-window-has-focus-and-how-to-change-it talks about determining the window with focus and provides a couple of options: you could use that technique and just run it in a loop and track the focus changes.

Comment: Do you have any idea if the focus messages you're talking about are the same as the 'focus events' described in the Tmux manual? `...focus events are requested from the terminal if supported and passed through to applications running in tmux.` Tmux isn't windowed and neither are the terminals inside it, so if not by X-window focus messages, then what kind of focus event could it be listening to? Thanks either way.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a stat on the terminal and get the Access or Modify times.

```
stat /dev/pts/2
```

Comment: What does that give you? Isn't the modified time updated whenever there's new output on the terminal? And I couldn't determine when the access time got updated from a short experiment.